# MS Word 2007 adding extra spaces between words

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

As I type, sometimes MS Word 2007 puts two spaces between words (and I only hit the space bar once). BUT THEN when I remove one of the extra spaces, MS Word adds an additional space between two different words somewhere in the same sentence. There are no "add-in" and the document is left justified. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is happening. When there are multiple double spaces between words in the same sentence, MS Word is only identifying one with the jagged underlining. When I remove the extra space, about a second later, Word identifies the next double space. I thought it was actually adding an extra space. So no, there is no gremlin in my computer, just a finger that hits the space bar too many times.